# ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy

Tags: excel, copy, row, vba

I am using ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy to copy rows that have a certain value in the "E" column cell, to another sheet.

It works great except for one problem.  I don't really want to copy the entire row, just the cells from A through N on the given row.

Is there something I can simply subsitute "EntireRow" to in ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy  ?

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
Sub ShortRow()
    Intersect(ActiveCell.EntireRow, Range("A:N")).Copy
End Sub
```

The intersection picks out the **A-N** part of the entire row.

Comment: @ninja97  glad to help!